# Improving your own suggested edit makes you leave the First Posts review queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing the First Posts (and Late Answers) review queue, after you suggest an edit, you're back in the review queue and the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button is activated. So far, so good, but when I realize I want to edit something else as well (I often forget the tags), I can click the 'edit' link again. When I'm done improving my suggested edit, I'm suddenly outside the review queue.

[image]

This does not happen if you have enough reputation (2k) to edit posts straight away; then you always stay in the review queue.