# Edit in First Post review takes you to the post not back to the review

Tags: bug, review

Something I've noticed today is that when editing in a First Post review after saving the edit I am taken to the post not back to the review as expected. This means if I want to keep doing something in the review, for example, comment, I have to go back or reopen the review up again by looking through my browser history.

I should be taken back to the review again as expected and what used to happen so I expect this is a bug.

---

I have only noticed this in the First Post queue but I imagine it happens in Late Answers as well.

---

In case it is a localised problem to me I am experiencing it on SFF, in Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: Reminds me of [Improving your own suggested edit makes you leave the First Posts review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298943/295232) - perhaps the developers can have a look at that while they're at it ...

Comment: Not just to continue the review, but also to press Done for that review, otherwise it's not recorded (twice today for me).

Comment: I've noticed the same thing (on several sites).